# How to save child object in DynamoDb EnhancedClient

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have data models like ParentClass and multiple child classes.

```
@Configuration
public class DynamoDBConfiguration {

@Value("${aws.dynamodb.table-name}")
private String tableName;

@Bean
public DynamoDbClient dynamoDbClient() {
    return DynamoDbClient.builder()
        .credentialsProvider(DefaultCredentialsProvider.create())
        .build();
}

@Bean
public DynamoDbEnhancedClient dynamoDbEnhancedClient() {
    return DynamoDbEnhancedClient.builder()
        .dynamoDbClient(dynamoDbClient())
        .build();
}

@Bean
public DynamoDBRepository<Parent> dbRepository() {
    DynamoDbTable<Parent> dynamoTable = dynamoDbEnhancedClient().table(tableName, TableSchema.fromClass(Parent.class));
    return new DynamoDBRepository<>(dynamoTable, Parent.class);
} 
}
```

Parent class has annotations

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
```

And Child class has annotations like

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@DynamoDbBean
@SuperBuilder
@DynamoDbBean
```

But while saving the parent class child object is not getting saved.

I am trying to migrate from DynamoDBMapper, which didn't require a schema, only a table name
But for enhanced clients, I have to specify a schema.